# Why is chmod recursively changing file permissions as well?

Tags: chmod, recursive

When I do `chmod _+x -R /dir` where "_" is any combination of (u,g,o,a), if after I do `chmod g+X -R /dir`, the files gain executable permissions as well.

Why does this happen? This behavior only happens if I use lower "x" first, then use upper "X".

**First example:**

```
[root@jesc5161 home]# chmod a-rwx -R finance/

[root@jesc5161 home]# ll
total 4
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root      17 May  2  2015 ec2-user
d---------. 3 root finance   65 Apr 22 22:12 finance
drwx------. 9 user user    4096 Apr 22 21:28 user

[root@jesc5161 home]# ll finance/
total 0
d---------. 2 root root    6 Apr 22 21:41 accounting
----------. 1 user user    0 Apr 22 22:06 myfile1
----------. 1 user finance 0 Apr 22 22:12 myfile2
----------. 1 user user    0 Apr 22 22:12 myfile3

[root@jesc5161 home]# chmod u+x -R finance/

[root@jesc5161 home]# ll
total 4
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root      17 May  2  2015 ec2-user
d--x------. 3 root finance   65 Apr 22 22:12 finance
drwx------. 9 user user    4096 Apr 22 21:28 user

[root@jesc5161 home]# ll finance/
total 0
d--x------. 2 root root    6 Apr 22 21:41 accounting
---x------. 1 user user    0 Apr 22 22:06 myfile1
---x------. 1 user finance 0 Apr 22 22:12 myfile2
---x------. 1 user user    0 Apr 22 22:12 myfile3
```

Here I only want to give group executable permission, but files also get executable permissions:

```
[root@jesc5161 home]# chmod g+X -R finance/

[root@jesc5161 home]# ll
total 4
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root      17 May  2  2015 ec2-user
d--x--x---. 3 root finance   65 Apr 22 22:12 finance
drwx------. 9 user user    4096 Apr 22 21:28 user

[root@jesc5161 home]# ll finance/
total 0
d--x--x---. 2 root root    6 Apr 22 21:41 accounting
---x--x---. 1 user user    0 Apr 22 22:06 myfile1
---x--x---. 1 user finance 0 Apr 22 22:12 myfile2
---x--x---. 1 user user    0 Apr 22 22:12 myfile3
```

**Another example:**

```
[root@jesc5161 home]# chmod a-rwx -R finance/

[root@jesc5161 home]# ll
total 4
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root      17 May  2  2015 ec2-user
d---------. 3 root finance   65 Apr 22 22:12 finance
drwx------. 9 user user    4096 Apr 22 21:28 user

[root@jesc5161 home]# ll finance/
total 0
d---------. 2 root root    6 Apr 22 21:41 accounting
----------. 1 user user    0 Apr 22 22:06 myfile1
----------. 1 user finance 0 Apr 22 22:12 myfile2
----------. 1 user user    0 Apr 22 22:12 myfile3

[root@jesc5161 home]# chmod u+rwx -R finance/

[root@jesc5161 home]# ll
total 4
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root      17 May  2  2015 ec2-user
drwx------. 3 root finance   65 Apr 22 22:12 finance
drwx------. 9 user user    4096 Apr 22 21:28 user

[root@jesc5161 home]# ll finance/
total 0
drwx------. 2 root root    6 Apr 22 21:41 accounting
-rwx------. 1 user user    0 Apr 22 22:06 myfile1
-rwx------. 1 user finance 0 Apr 22 22:12 myfile2
-rwx------. 1 user user    0 Apr 22 22:12 myfile3
```

Again, I only want to give group executable permission, but files gain executable permissions as well.

```
[root@jesc5161 home]# chmod g+X -R finance/

[root@jesc5161 home]# ll
total 4
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root      17 May  2  2015 ec2-user
drwx--x---. 3 root finance   65 Apr 22 22:12 finance
drwx------. 9 user user    4096 Apr 22 21:28 user

[root@jesc5161 home]# ll finance/
total 0
drwx--x---. 2 root root    6 Apr 22 21:41 accounting
-rwx--x---. 1 user user    0 Apr 22 22:06 myfile1
-rwx--x---. 1 user finance 0 Apr 22 22:12 myfile2
-rwx--x---. 1 user user    0 Apr 22 22:12 myfile3
```

**Here is an example where "it works" but as you can see I did NOT use lower "x" prior to using upper "X"**

```
[root@jesc5161 home]# chmod a-rwx -R finance/

[root@jesc5161 home]# ll
total 4
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root      17 May  2  2015 ec2-user
d---------. 3 root finance   65 Apr 22 22:12 finance
drwx------. 9 user user    4096 Apr 22 21:28 user

[root@jesc5161 home]# ll finance/
total 0
d---------. 2 root root    6 Apr 22 21:41 accounting
----------. 1 user user    0 Apr 22 22:06 myfile1
----------. 1 user finance 0 Apr 22 22:12 myfile2
----------. 1 user user    0 Apr 22 22:12 myfile3

[root@jesc5161 home]# chmod a+rw -R finance/

[root@jesc5161 home]# ll
total 4
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root      17 May  2  2015 ec2-user
drw-rw-rw-. 3 root finance   65 Apr 22 22:12 finance
drwx------. 9 user user    4096 Apr 22 21:28 user

[root@jesc5161 home]# ll finance/
total 0
drw-rw-rw-. 2 root root    6 Apr 22 21:41 accounting
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 user user    0 Apr 22 22:06 myfile1
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 user finance 0 Apr 22 22:12 myfile2
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 user user    0 Apr 22 22:12 myfile3

[root@jesc5161 home]# chmod g+X -R finance/

[root@jesc5161 home]# ll
total 4
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root      17 May  2  2015 ec2-user
drw-rwxrw-. 3 root finance   65 Apr 22 22:12 finance
drwx------. 9 user user    4096 Apr 22 21:28 user

[root@jesc5161 home]# ll finance/
total 0
drw-rwxrw-. 2 root root    6 Apr 22 21:41 accounting
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 user user    0 Apr 22 22:06 myfile1
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 user finance 0 Apr 22 22:12 myfile2
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 user user    0 Apr 22 22:12 myfile3

[root@jesc5161 home]# chmod o+X -R finance/

[root@jesc5161 home]# ll
total 4
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root      17 May  2  2015 ec2-user
drw-rwxrwx. 3 root finance   65 Apr 22 22:12 finance
drwx------. 9 user user    4096 Apr 22 21:28 user

[root@jesc5161 home]# ll finance/
total 0
drw-rwxrwx. 2 root root    6 Apr 22 21:41 accounting
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 user user    0 Apr 22 22:06 myfile1
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 user finance 0 Apr 22 22:12 myfile2
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 user user    0 Apr 22 22:12 myfile3

[root@jesc5161 home]# chmod u+X -R finance/

[root@jesc5161 home]# ll
total 4
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root      17 May  2  2015 ec2-user
drwxrwxrwx. 3 root finance   65 Apr 22 22:12 finance
drwx------. 9 user user    4096 Apr 22 21:28 user

[root@jesc5161 home]# ll finance/
total 0
drwxrwxrwx. 2 root root    6 Apr 22 21:41 accounting
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 user user    0 Apr 22 22:06 myfile1
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 user finance 0 Apr 22 22:12 myfile2
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 user user    0 Apr 22 22:12 myfile3
```

Comment: `+X` means "set execute bit if any of user/group/other already has execute bit set, or is directory". Why are you surprised that it sets the group execute bit on every file after you've explicitly set the user/other execute bit on every file? What are you trying to do that you expect `-X` to solve?

Comment: @MichaelHomer I thought `+X` only affected directories. So if I use `u+x -R`, the execute bit is now "set" (for files AND directories ? or only files?) therefore any permission changes using `+X` will now affect files and directories?

Comment: [Yes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/chmod.html#tag_20_17_13)

Comment: @MichaelHomer Is there only 1 execute bit per file/directory? Or are there 3 (one for each option: u,g,o). I believe this is part of my confusion.

Comment: There are three, one for each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`+X` means](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/chmod.html#tag_20_17_13) to set the execute bit:

> if the file is a directory or if the current (unmodified) file mode bits have at least one of the execute bits (S_IXUSR, S_IXGRP, or S_IXOTH) set. It shall be ignored if the file is not a directory and none of the execute bits are set in the current file mode bits.

Once you've run `chmod -R _+x dir`, the execute bit is set for at least some of user/group/other for every file (that you have permission to modify). That means `-X` applies to all of those files as well.

If you only want to affect directories, and there are no other executable files in the tree, you can run the `+X` command before other modifications. Otherwise, you [can use `find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html):

```
find dir -type d -exec echo chmod g+x {} \+
```

That finds all directories (`-type d`) in `dir` and executes `echo chmod g+x` on them all, with `{}` turned into all the paths.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much. Also, why `+` at the end of the command and not `;`?

Comment: Because otherwise someone will moan at me that this single-use command is slightly inefficient (it would run `chmod` once per path, instead of once with as many files as possible).

Comment: +1.  I'll moan that you don't need to backslash-escape the `+`.   you can't win :-) someone will always find something to moan about.